# GraphQL: Can an interface be used to unify two types whose equivalent properties have different names?

Tags: graphql

Suppose my schema includes two types:

```
type Dog {
    breed: String
}

type Cat {
    breedName: string
}
```

Is there a way to define an Interface that `Dog` and `Cat` both extend, and which has a field for breed, even when that field has different names in the two types? I suspect the answer is no, but at first I thought maybe field aliases might work here. Yes, I realize you could change the field name in either of the two types, but I'm looking for an alternative because in my actual use case, the types are not changeable at this point. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an alias when *querying* the field, but at the end of the day, whatever the field is called in the Interface, it must also be called that in the implementing type. The [spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Objects) is pretty explicit about this requirement:

> An object type must be a super‐set of all interfaces it implements... The object type must include a field of the same name for every field defined in an interface.

You might consider utilizing a union instead of an interface to still get the benefit of having an abstract type without having to implement specific fields. Or just omit the `breed` field from the interface altogether.